# How to extract multiple json objects from within a string and preserve other text in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm wanting to extract multiple json objects from within a text string, whilst preserving the text either side of the json. The use case for this is to format a log file, which has text statements interspersed with json objects.

An example string for which I may need to perform this on is as follows...

```
beforetext{"Message":"The request is invalid.","ModelState":{"Id":["Unknown 
contract"]}}middletext{"Message":"The request is invalid.","ModelState": 
{"Id":["Unknown contract"]}}aftertext
```

I made some headway by looking for the { and } and with the indexes I was able to extract and slice down the string until I had my json objects and my other text.

The problem is that a json object can have multiple { and } characters, like in the example above, and I can't pinpoint where one object definitively starts and ends.

Once I have the json extracted, and the text between, I'll be looking to display like this..

```
beforetext
{
  "Message": "The request is invalid.",
  "ModelState": {
    "Id": [
      "Unknown contract"
    ]
  }
}
middletext
{
  "Message": "The request is invalid.",
  "ModelState": {
    "Id": [
      "Unknown contract"
    ]
  }
}
aftertext
```

I've looked into regex but I've not been able to find a clear solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you can be certain that before/middle/after-text don't contain any `{}` characters, nor do any of the json string values, you can keep a count of your "depth" into a json object - each time you encounter a `{`, increment your counter, each time you encounter a `}`, decrement your counter. When your counter hits 0, you've got a complete JSON object. If you think that your text might contain these characters, you'll need to walk the string, keeping track of what state the cursor is currently in. (See https://sites.google.com/site/gson/streaming)

Comment: Thanks @AndrewRueckert. I was able to implement a solution (added below) based on this idea that fits my needs.

Answer (score 1):

It's not too hard to parse this yourself so long as you can reasonably predict the kind of string you will be dealing with. You can keep a stack of your delimiters and when the stack arrives at or departs a length of zero, you know you are at a boundary. You can suck strings in as whole units to allow them to contain anything (except `"`).

This will assume the strings and containers are balanced, but it's not hard to add basic error checking to this kind of parser. I changed your data to add a few more difficulties (like starting with `[` and including `{}` in strings)

```js
let s = 'beforetext[{"Message":"The request is {invalid.}"},{"ModelState":{"Id":["Unknown contract"]}}]middletext{"Message":"The request is invalid.","ModelState": {"Id":["Unknown contract"]}}aftertext'

function balance(s){
    let opens = ['{', '['], closes = ['}', ']'],  // define opening and closing delimiters
    res = [], current = '', stack = []

    for (let i = 0; i<s.length; i++){
        let char = s[i]
        if (char == '"'){                         // take strings as units to allow them to contain delimters
            let next = s.indexOf('"', i+1)
            current += s.substring(i, next+1)
            i = next 
        }
        else if(opens.includes(char)) {           // new opening, push to stack
            if (stack.length == 0){
                res.push(current)
                current = char
            }
            stack.push(char) 
        } else if (closes.includes(char)) {       // new closing pop
            stack.pop()
            if (stack.length == 0) {
                res.push(current + char)
                current = ''
            }
        }
        else {current += char}
    }
    res.push(current)
    return res
}

console.log(balance(s).join('\n\n'))
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this by implementing the suggestion by Andrew Rueckert

- I iterated through every character in the string.
- If I encountered an '{' I incremented the depth by 1. If it's a '}' I decremented the depth by 1.
- Whenever the depth was at 0, I knew these were my start and end indexes for the json.
- I stored the text up to the start index, and the json as an object. I then pushed these properties onto an array.
- Some additional logic to account for the end of a string where there is text remaining but no json, and if the string doesn't contain any '{' or '}'.

Example...

```
jsonObjects() 
{
  var jsonString = this.value;
  var jsonObjects = [];
  var remainingString = '';
  var depth = 0;
  var indexStart = 0;
  var indexEnd = 0;
  var pointer = 0;

  if (!jsonString.includes('{') && !jsonString.includes('}')) {
    jsonObjects.push({ "pretext": jsonString, "json": null });
  }
  else {
    for (var i = 0; i < jsonString.length; i++) 
    {
      if (jsonString.charAt(i) === '{') {
        if (depth === 0) {
          indexStart = i;
        }
        depth++;
      }
      else if (jsonString.charAt(i) === '}') {
        depth--;
        if (depth === 0) {
          indexEnd = i;

          var finalJson = JSON.parse(jsonString.substring(indexStart, indexEnd + 1));
          var gapText = jsonString.substring(pointer, indexStart);
          jsonObjects.push({ "pretext": gapText, "json": finalJson });

          pointer = indexEnd + 1;
          remainingString = jsonString.substring(pointer, jsonString.length);

          if (!remainingString.includes('{') && !remainingString.includes('}')) {
            jsonObjects.push({ "pretext": remainingString, "json": null });
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return jsonObjects;   
}
```

With some conditional formatting in vue the result looks quite nice..

```
<div v-for="jsonObject in jsonObjects" v-bind:key="jsonObject.pretext"> 
  <p>{{ jsonObject.pretext }}</p>
  <vue-json-pretty :deep="1" v-if="jsonObject.json != null" :data="jsonObject.json"></vue-json-pretty>   
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you want all three as group but if not you can split as below. This will give you array with all json objects.

```
let yourString = 'beforetext{"Message":"The request is invalid.","ModelState":{"Id":["Unknown contract"]}}middletext{"Message":"The request is invalid.","ModelState": {"Id":["Unknown contract"]}}aftertext'

yourString.split(/beforetext\b|middletext\b|aftertext\b/).filter(json=>json)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is looking for a C# version:

```
var message = "{}...{\"test\":\"\"}.[{\"test\":\"me\"}]....{\"test\":{\"inner:\":\"me\"}}...{";
message = Regex.Unescape(message); // remove the backslashes.
var openings = new List<char> { '{', '[' };
var closings = new List<char> { '}', ']' };
var stack = new Stack<char>();
var matches = new List<string>();
var current = new StringBuilder();
for (var i = 0; i < message.Length; i++)
{
    var ch = message[i];
    if (ch == '"')
    {
        // Look for ending '"' to quickly navigate JSON fields and values.
        // TODO What if there is no closing '"'.. indexOf will crash.
        var next = message.IndexOf('"', i + 1);
        current.Append(message.Substring(i, next - i + 1));
        i = next;
    }
    else if (openings.Contains(ch))
    {
        current.Append(ch);
        stack.Push(ch);
    }
    else if (closings.Contains(ch))
    {
        current.Append(ch);
        stack.Pop();

        // TODO This can work too: '{ [ } }' which is invalid JSON.
        if (stack.Count == 0)
        {
            matches.Add(current.ToString());
            current.Clear();
        }
    }
    else if (stack.Count > 0)
    {
        current.Append(ch);
    }
}
```

will produce:

> {}, {"test":""}, [{"test":"me"}], {"test":{"inner:":"me"}}